# getting call stack of interrupted task at interrupt handler

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, callstack

I am writing a PCI device driver in LKM. At the PCI interrupt handler, I want to access and/or print the stack frames of the interrupted task. What functions should I call to get the stack pointer and the stack frames?

Comment: I’m not sure what did you mean. LKML stands for Linux Kernel Mailing List. Anyway to dump stack the *dump_stack()* is used.

Comment: I meant LKM. Fixed. If I call dump_stack, will it dump the interrupt stack or the interrupted task&#39;s stack? @0andriy